# Sorting on a parameter field in Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to write a sub-transformatino that sorts a stream based on an arbitrary field (I'm going to need to sort several streams over the course of this entire project, and I'd like to just re-use 1 transformation and change the name of the field I'm sorting by). The problem is no matter what I try, I get an error saying that `"The field ${SORT_FIELD} specified in the "Sort Fields" step is not in the steps input stream."` (${SORT_FIELD} is the variable holding the name of the field I want to sort by and the "Sort Fields" is the name of the actual "Sort Rows" step.

`${SORT_FIELD}` is listed in the mapping input specification as a required field. I'm also listing `${SORT_FIELD}` as a parameter to the sub-transformation (in addition to having it inherit all variables from the parent transformation).

Is there any way to pass a field name as a parameter to a sort rows step so I don't have to manually input the field I want to sort by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can do that via metadata injection. I'm pretty sure that the sort rows step does support metadata injection. Check out matt casters blog on the subject..

Comment: Googling for meta-injection for sort transformations led to a JIRA posting indicating this will be available for Kettle 5.0 (currently in an alpha build I believe). Unfortunately, I'm on 4.2, so that new feature won't help.

Comment: ok no probs. Keep an eye on the jira though, quite a few of the 5.0 features are filtering down into 4.4...  But yes; doesnt help you now.

Comment: Sounds good. Accepting this as it will ultimately become the correct answer.